# Please confirm that $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln(x)\sin(x)\cos\left(x\over \sqrt{\phi}\right)\over x} dx={1\over 2}\pi \left(\ln\phi-\gamma\right)$

Tags: calculus

Observe this integral

Where $\phi={\sqrt{5}+1\over 2}$

and $\gamma=0.5772156...$ is Euler's Constant

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln(x)\sin(x)\cos\left(x\over \sqrt{\phi}\right)\over x}\mathrm dx={1\over 2}\pi \left(\ln\phi-\gamma\right)\tag1$$

$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln(x)\sin(x)\cos\left(ax\right)\over x}\mathrm dx\tag2$$

$$I^{'}(a)=-\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln(x)\sin(x)\sin\left(ax\right)}\mathrm dx\tag3$$

Using

$2\sin A\sin B=\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)$

$\sin x\sin(ax)=\cos[(1-a)x]-\cos[(1+a)x]$

$$I^{'}(a)=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos[(1-a)x]\ln x \mathrm dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos[(1+a)x]\ln x\mathrm dx\tag4$$

$$\int \cos[(1-a)x]\ln x \mathrm dx={\sin[(1-a)x]\ln x\over 1-a}-\int {\sin[(1-a)x]\over x}\tag 5$$

$$\int \cos[(1-a)x]\ln x \mathrm dx={\sin[(1+a)x]\ln x\over 1+a}-\int {\sin[(1+a)x]\over x}\tag 6$$

$(5)$ and $(6)$ showed divgergent integrals

This approach  I have tried is not working, what other method can we use to verify $(1)?$

Comment: i somehow know this kind of questions...do you know a guy called 'bui'?

Comment: This looks like something that could be calculated with Frullani's Theorem easily. I'll take a stab at it soon

Comment: The presence of $\phi$ is really irrelevant here; we generally have that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln(x)\sin(x)\cos\left(x\over \sqrt{\phi}\right)\over x}\mathrm dx = -\frac{1}{4} \pi  \left(\log \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)+2 \gamma \right)$$

Comment: @tired: there are many questions on integrals with similar pattern and even I think most of it comes from same source. Anyway this does not matter much as long as we get good questions and more importantly great answers like the one here by user Felix Marin.

Comment: Through Integration by Parts, we find that
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)\sin(x)\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}{x} dx 
=L-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Si}\left(\left[1+\frac{1}{n}\right]x\right)-\operatorname{Si}\left(\left[\frac{1}{n}-1\right]x\right)}{x} dx$$ which is so close to being a Frullani Integral. Unfortunately, both $L$ and the rightmost integral blow up, and the easiest way to show that their singularities cancel seems to me, thus far at least, to evaluate the integral by a different method

Comment: Welcome back ...

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai are you welcoming back this post?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, I am welcoming back the person who posted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\ln\pars{x}\sin\pars{x}\cos\pars{x\over \root{\phi}} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\ln\pars{x}\sin\pars{\bracks{1 + \phi^{-1/2}}x}\over x}\,\dd x +
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\ln\pars{x}\sin\pars{\bracks{1 - \phi^{-1/2}}x}\over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\ln\pars{x/\bracks{1 + \phi^{-1/2}}}\sin\pars{x}\over x}\,\dd x +
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\ln\pars{x/\bracks{1 - \phi^{-1/2}}}\sin\pars{x}\over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{1 - \phi^{-1}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x + \int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{x}\,{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{\pi \over 4}\,\ln\pars{1 - \phi^{-1}} +
\bbox[#ffd,10px]{\ds{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{x}\,{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[#ffd,10px]{\ds{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{x}\,{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}} =
\left.\partiald{}{\mu}\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\mu - 1}\expo{\ic x}
\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 0^{+}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.\partiald{}{\mu}\Im\int_{0}^{\infty\ic}x^{\mu - 1}\expo{\ic\pars{1 - \mu}\pi/2}\expo{-x}
\pars{-\ic}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 0^{+}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{\sin\pars{\mu\,{\pi \over 2}}
\Gamma\pars{\mu}}_{\ \mu\ =\ 0^{+}} =
\left.{1 \over 2}\,\pi\,\partiald{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}}{\mu}
\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 0^{+}} = -\,{1 \over 2}\,\pi\gamma
\end{align}

---

$$
\bbx{\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\ln\pars{x}\sin\pars{x}\cos\pars{x\over \root{\phi}} \over x}\,\dd x =
{\pi \over 2}\bracks{-\,{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{1 - \phi^{-1}} - \gamma}}}
$$

> Note that
>   $\ds{-\ln\pars{1 - \phi^{-1}} = \ln\pars{3 + \root{5} \over 2}}$.

Since $\ds{\phi^{2} - \phi - 1 = 0 \implies
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{1 - \phi^{-1}}  =
\ln\pars{\phi}}$, an alternative expression is
$$
\bbx{\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\ln\pars{x}\sin\pars{x}\cos\pars{x\over \root{\phi}} \over x}\,\dd x =
\color{#f00}{+}\,{1 \over 2}\,\pi\bracks{\ln\pars{\phi} - \gamma}}}
$$

Comment: The way the OP writes it is correct, your's and the OP's are equivalent forms. Well, actually the OP's gives $0.15080...$ and your's gives $-0.15080...$ so one of you has a sign error. If I remember correctly Mathematica sides with the OP, but I would have to check

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I check my answer with $\texttt{Mathematica}$. It yields my result. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... Ok. I suppose the sign error might be with the OP then.

Comment: There is a typo just after third $=$ sign. Either you keep $\pi/2$ or the $(\sin x) /x$ integral but not both otherwise you get a $\pi^{2}/4$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Fixed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: let $$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^a\sin(x)\cos\left(x\over \sqrt{\phi}\right)dx$$ and then use Mellon transform to calculate it. Finally evaluate $I'(-1)$ which will be the answer.